# Dual Purpose Middle Click

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I use middle click to open new windows in Chrome solely.
I am also used to using middle click to essentially paste coming from Linux.

Is there with autohotkey to keep both functionalities present?
This works for the paste functionality for now.

```
mbutton::
  sendinput ^{v}
  return
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for example you can simply prefix the hotkey with a tilde:

```
~mbutton::
  sendinput ^{v}
  return
```

Which makes the hotkey non-blocking (lets the event pass further).
But generally it is not a good idea - it means you will have a system-wide shortcut which lets the application consume this event as well.
E.g. in Chrome, if you have an active input cursor in some form, then clicking m-button on some link will paste the text into the form AND open a new tab.  In case of opening a link it might be actually ok, but imagine if some other software has e.g. "select all" bound to middle-click or something like that. So it should be used with caution.

IMO a better idea would be to make some application-specific script. This can be made with the `#if` directive. See [Context-dependent app](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm) . So for example you could have a hotkey only when Chrome is active and further check whether in Chrome you have input cursor active or not (might be possible, but I am not sure).

Comment: This prevents middle press from scrolling.  Is there a way to fix this?